# Using vertx TestSuite with junit

Tags: java, gradle, junit, vert.x

I been following vertx junit [integration example](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_junit_integration), but I don't understand how to run TestSuite from junit @test method or junit @Suite.SuiteClasses?

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class RunOnContextJUnitTestSuite {

  @Rule
  public RunTestOnContext rule = new RunTestOnContext();

  @Test
  public void testSomething(TestContext context) {
    // Use the underlying vertx instance
    Vertx vertx = rule.vertx();
  }
}
```

I want to run vertx TestSuite tests from Gradle, but it only integrated with junit and I don't know how to run TestSuite in junit.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of options
1. Run the individual tests from the IDE (IntelliJ and eclipse both work)
2. Run the tests using maven

http://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples has a bunch of examples that show you exactly what you need to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
testCompile group: 'io.vertx', name: 'vertx-junit5', version: "$vertx_version"
testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0'
```

And I did the following:

```
@ExtendWith(VertxExtension::class) abstract class BaseTest {

    companion object {
        lateinit var injector : Injector

        init {
            // things that may need to be setup before companion class member variables are instantiated
        }

        @BeforeAll
        @JvmStatic
        fun deploy_verticle(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext) {

            Json.mapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())
            val rxVertx = io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx(vertx)
            injector = Guice.createInjector(TestModule(rxVertx))
            val main = injector.getInstance(MainVerticle::class.java)
            vertx.deployVerticle(main, testContext.succeeding { id -> testContext.completeNow() })

        }

    } }
```

And then I extend the baseTest class like this:

```
class SomeTestClass: BaseTest() {
    @AfterEach
    fun `Check that the verticle is still there`(vertx: Vertx) {
        Assertions.assertTrue(!vertx.deploymentIDs().isEmpty())
    }

    @Test
    fun someTest(vertx: Vertx, testContext: VertxTestContext){

     ...
    }}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: "I want to run vertx TestSuite tests from Gradle, but it only integrated with junit and I don't know how to run TestSuite in junit."

Comment: So I am missing here something, where do you define the TestSuite and what tests are going to be part of it?